# Editing multiple array values (if they exist)

Tags: php, arrays, editing

Well guys i've been struggling with this for about 5 hours now and i realise my brain is fried thought i better get some people who know what they are doing :p Now i just have to explain the problem properly.

I want to display all the goal scorers with just their name and goal time for each separate goal after it like: 
Carlton Dickson (23, 53) Danniel Tasker (1).

The only way i could think to do this is replace the array with a new one which has in it all the goals in element. So making one row for the names and one row with all the goals in them. Maybe i am not looking at this the right way?

Cheers dudes.

```
array(8) {   

    [0]=>   array(3) {  

         ["fname"]=>
         string(7) "Carlton"
         ["sname"]=>
         string(7) "Dickson"
         ["time"]=>
         string(2) "23"   
    }   

    [1]=>   array(3) {

         ["fname"]=>
         string(7) "Carlton"
         ["sname"]=>
         string(7) "Dickson"
         ["time"]=>
         string(2) "53"  
    }  

    [2]=>   array(3) {

         ["fname"]=>
         string(6) "Daniel"
         ["sname"]=>
         string(6) "Tasker"
         ["time"]=>
         string(1) "1"   
    }
```

Comment: can you show what the desired input and output is in more detail? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rebuild your array this way:

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $player) {
    $name = $player['fname'] . " " . $player["sname"];
    if(!array_key_exists($name, $newArray)) {
        $newArray[$name] = array();
    }
    $newArray[$name][] = $player['time'];
}
```

The resulting array will be:

```
Array
(
    [Carlton Dickson] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
            [1] => 53
        )

    [Daniel Tasker] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)
```

i.e. the key is the name, and the value is an array of the goals. Of course you can also concatenate the goals as a string, it depends on what else you want to do with the data.

Then printing is just a matter of traversing the array:

```
foreach($newArray as $player => $goals) {
    echo $player . " (" . implode(',', $goals) . ") <br />"; // or PHP_EOL
}
```

Comment: Dude you're a genuis, i didn't think of using names as the key. Dam it man :) thats so simple just add all the times into the array rather then editing the current one. 

Thanks very much, little annoying you did what took me hours and didn't finish :)

Cheers for checking as well Crazy Juggler.

Comment: @Jamie Hutber: Your welcome. Yeah, using data as keys can make some things pretty easy. If you build your array dynamically anyway, you can already build it this way from the beginning... Happy coding!

Comment: @Felix I saw your previous answer where you used + as the concatenation operator. Too much Python, eh? LOL

Comment: Heh ye, well i enter the data for the games and part of that is data for each goal scored. I'm already grabbing that all from the database so it was a case of just whittling it down.

Comment: @NullUserException ha ye noticed that as well.

Comment: @NullUserException, @Jamie Hutber: This time, it was too much JavaScript... such things can happen :o) (actually PHP is the only language I know that uses `.` for string concatenation)

Comment: hehe i'd swap knowing how to do the array stuff off the cuff for getting to much js mixed up ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scorers = array();

foreach ($goals as $goal) {
    $name = "{$goal['fname']} {$goal['sname']}";
    $scorers[$name] = isset($scorers[$name]) ? "{$scorers[$name]}, {$goal['time']}" : $goal['time'];
}

foreach ($scorers as $scorer => $goals) {
    echo "$scorer ($goals)";
}
```

Assuming you have a `$goals` array like so:

```
$goals = array(
    array('fname' => 'Carlton', 'sname' => 'Dickson', 'time' => '23'),
    array('fname' => 'Carlton', 'sname' => 'Dickson', 'time' => '53'),
    array('fname' => 'Daniel',  'sname' => 'Tasker',  'time' => '1')
);
```

Comment: yep it certainly isn't :) You can't ever have more then 11 goal scorers anyway. I honestly didn't know everybody at stack overflow was so dam helpful.

Comment: @Felix Nope. It won't work exactly right if I use concatenation; unless I add lines of code.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was a bit confused by the expression you use with the ternary operator... tricky ;)